# Uploadify sizeLimit issue

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, uploadify

I am using uploadify in a project with the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#uploadify").uploadify({
        'uploader': '_assets/flash/uploadify.swf',
        'script': 'uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg': '_assets/images/nav/cancel.png',
        'folder': 'uploads',
        'queueID': 'fileQueue',
        'auto': true,
        'multi': true,
        'sizeLimit': 20971520,
        'fileExt': '*.eps;*.jpg;*.pdf;*.psd;*.mov;*.ai;*.png;*.doc;*.docx;*.ppt;*.pptx;*.indd;*.bmp;*.dwg;*.pct;*.txt;*.wmv',
        'fileDesc': 'We accept graphics and text files only!',
        'buttonImg': '_assets/images/nav/uploadbutton.png',
        'wmode': 'transparent',
        'width': 143,
        'height': 53,
        onAllComplete: function() {
            $('#forupload').hide();
            $('#confirm').fadeIn();
        }
    });

});
```

The php file this makes a request to is uploadify.php:

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);


if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // $fileTypes  = str_replace('*.','',$_REQUEST['fileext']);
    // $fileTypes  = str_replace(';','|',$fileTypes);
    // $typesArray = split('\|',$fileTypes);
    // $fileParts  = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    // if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$typesArray)) {
        // Uncomment the following line if you want to make the directory if it doesn't exist
        // mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0755, true);

        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo "1";



    //Send confirmation email

    require_once('_mailClasses/class.phpmailer.php');
    include_once("_mailClasses/class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

    $mail             = new PHPMailer();

    $body             = 'There is a new online order. Please check your order folder.';
    //$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = "mail.splashoflondon.com";      // SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                              // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
    // 1 = errors and messages
    // 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                           // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Host       = "mail.splashoflondon.com";      // sets the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 25;                         // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username   = "orders@splashoflondon.com";    // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password   = "blablabla";                        // SMTP account password

    $mail->SetFrom('orders@splashoflondon.com', 'Splash of London');

    $mail->AddReplyTo("sales@splashoflondon.com","Adolphus");

    $mail->Subject    = "Online Order";

    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $address = "sales@splashoflondon.com";
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "Splash Order Managment");
    $mail->Send();

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }

}
```

The problem is it disregards the 20mb size limit and doesn't allow the user to upload files bigger than 1.something mb.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my current php.ini:

```
    register_globals = Off

post_max_size = 20M
upload_max_filesize = 20M


[Zend]

zend_optimizer.optimization_level=15

zend_extension_manager.optimizer=/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer-2.5.10

zend_extension_manager.optimizer_ts=/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer_TS-2.5.10

zend_optimizer.version=2.5.10a

zend_extension = /usr/local/lib/ioncube_loader_lin_4.4.so



zend_extension=/usr/local/Zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so

zend_extension_ts=/usr/local/Zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager_TS.so
```

Comment: @XGreen: what webserver are you using? apache and nginx have config settings for max POST size for example.

Comment: I am using Apache from HOSTPAPA a canadian provider. On the CPANEL of the domain in the php configuration section it says: File Uploads  upload_max_filesize  Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.  64M

Comment: How do I alter the config setting for max post size? Do I need to add a .htaccess to the project root? what is the correct syntax which I need to write?

Comment: In apache the setting is called LimitRequestBody. See eg http://www.512kbps.com/2008/03/10/modsecurity-request-body-is-larger-than-the-configured-limit/

Comment: I added my php.ini where I added the max size and upload size directives but it has no effect

Comment: I tried adding php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200 to my .htacess but it causes my server to crash and show an internal error page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try subscribing to the onError handler in your uploadify call. Something like this, after the onAllComplete handler...

```
onError: function (a, b, c, d) {
     if (d.status == 404)
        alert('Could not find upload script.');
     else if (d.type === "HTTP")
        alert('error '+d.type+": "+d.status);
     else if (d.type ==="File Size")
        alert(c.name+' '+d.type+' Limit: '+Math.round(d.sizeLimit/1024)+'KB');
     else
        alert('error '+d.type+": "+d.text);
}
```